# Javascript replace a function with a new one containing dynamic contents

Tags: javascript, function, replace

My Javascript knowledge is less experienced, so I might use wrong descriptions in the following.

I have an object in a static .js file:

```
var Info = {
    methodA: function() {
        // Call methodB.
        this.methodB('test');
    },

    methodB: function(value) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, in an .aspx file, I create a function methodC(value) with varying contents (depending on some data), which I want to insert instead of the above definition of methodB(value):

```
...
var methodC = function(value) {
    // Do different stuff
}
...
```

My idea has so far been to replace methodB with methodC in the following fashion:

```
...
Info.methodB = methodC;
...
```

Using IE's buildin developer tool, I get the following error when calling this.methodB('test'); from Info.methodA():

> Object doesn’t support this property
>   or method

Removing the 'this' from this.methodB('test') results in the error:

> Object expected

I don't get any errors using FireBug - probably because I use various frameworks, which might catch the error.

How should I do this or should I use a completely different approach?

Regards, Casper

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What error message do you get? Otherwise what's the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: I have added details regarding the errors I recieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work, you are doing it the right way. The problem lays elsewhere.

update:
This should still work as long as you call methodA on an object, eg Info.methodA().

Maybe you are not understanding the error messages ?

"Object doesn’t support this property or method" means that in the expression "this.methodB()", *this* doesn't have a property named "methodB". So it means that *this* is not *Info* when the code of *methodA* is executed.

"Object expected" means that the variable *methodB* is unknown in the current execution context. Of course it is, since *methodB* is never a variable, only a property of *Info*.

To debug your problem, you need to know what is *this* when a code is executed, and why it's not what you think it should be. When you call *Info.methodA()*, *this* is set to be *Info* when *methodA* begins its execution.

Comment: Changing this.methodB('test') to directly call methodC('test') works - thus my implementation of methodC(value) should work. I know how to debug variables, but how to debug functions/methods, I haven't figured out yet :)

Comment: How can I see 'this' in IE's developer tool?

Comment: @Alsciende: In Firebug I can see the 'this' variable. But in IE's developer tool, I need to use the console and write something like: var a = this; Then 'this' is visible amongst the other local variables.